# Identity of this plant (yellow snap-dragon looking flower)

Tags: identification, flowers

Could someone identify this plant?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure, because we don't have a close-up of the flowers, but it looks like Oncidium flexuosum to me.  Here is an overall picture of the flowers, and a flower close up.  You can compare these to yours and let us know if it fits.  This is a species of orchid, by the way.

Overall plant:
[image: Plant view]

Flower close-up:
[image: Flower close-up]

Comment: This does appear to be it! Thanks TeresaMcgH!